# How to use 2 or more jdbcTemplate with spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I want to use 2 or more jdbcTemplate in my project using application.properties.I try but got runtime exception.

########## My application.properties:-

```
     spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ccm_new
     spring.datasource.username=test
     spring.datasource.password=test

      spring.oracledatasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mastera
   spring.oracledatasource.password=test
   spring.oracledatasource.username=test
   spring.oracledatasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

     @Bean(name = "dsMaster") ############
     @Primary
     @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.oracledatasource")
     public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
     return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

      @Bean(name = "jdbcMaster") #############
        public JdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dsMaster") DataSource dsMaster)
           {
       return new JdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
      }
```

################I use the mysql connection normally but on use of oracle connection i got

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:371)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:446)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
    at `enter code here`

Comment: Di you check the @Qualifier("dsMaster") DataSource dsMaster properties?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.12.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Comment: hope my answer helped you

Comment: I Write the correct code in below last section please check and it work now i have 2 jdbc template i.e oracle as well mysql thats means now i can create (n) jdbc template for use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it where i am wrong,I want to make mysql connection through application.properties without @bean configuration.If you want to take 2 or more connection you just need to define all the datasource with their @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mysqldatasource") different prifix other than "spring.datasource".prifix " spring.datasource" use only when we need to make connection from only one database.Here is the final working code example:-

application.properties

```
 spring.mysqldatasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 spring.mysqldatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ccm_new
 spring.mysqldatasource.username=test
 spring.mysqldatasource.password=test
 spring.mysqldatasource.dbcp2.initial-size=5
 spring.mysqldatasource.dbcp2.max-total=15
 spring.mysqldatasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true



spring.oracledatasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mastera
spring.oracledatasource.password=test
spring.oracledatasource.username=test
spring.oracledatasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.oracledatasource.dbcp2.initial-size=5
spring.oracledatasource.dbcp2.max-total=15
spring.oracledatasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true



 @Configuration
 public class PrototypeUtility {
 @Bean(name = "dsMaster")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.oracledatasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
@Bean(name = "jdbcMaster")
public JdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dsMaster") DataSource dsMaster) {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
}

@Bean(name = "dsMasterMysql")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mysqldatasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSourceMysql() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
@Bean(name = "jdbcMasterMysql")
public JdbcTemplate masterMysqlJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dsMasterMysql") DataSource dsMasterMysql) {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dsMasterMysql);
}
  }
```

and then i autowired the both connection :-

```
     @Autowired
      private JdbcTemplate jdbcMasterMysql;

     @Autowired
     public JdbcTemplate jdbcMaster;
```

This code run successfully for me .
If any one have doubt,Don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I got it where i am wrong,I want to make mysql connection through application.properties without @bean configuration.If you want to take 2 or more connection you just need to define all the datasource with their @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mysqldatasource") different prifix other than "spring.datasource".prifix " spring.datasource" use only when we need to make connection from only one database.Here is the final working code example:-

application.properties

```
spring.mysqldatasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 spring.mysqldatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ccm_new
 spring.mysqldatasource.username=test
 spring.mysqldatasource.password=test
 spring.mysqldatasource.dbcp2.initial-size=5
 spring.mysqldatasource.dbcp2.max-total=15
 spring.mysqldatasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true



spring.oracledatasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:mastera
spring.oracledatasource.password=test
spring.oracledatasource.username=test
spring.oracledatasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.oracledatasource.dbcp2.initial-size=5
spring.oracledatasource.dbcp2.max-total=15
spring.oracledatasource.dbcp2.pool-prepared-statements=true



 @Configuration
 public class PrototypeUtility {
 @Bean(name = "dsMaster")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.oracledatasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
@Bean(name = "jdbcMaster")
public JdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dsMaster") DataSource dsMaster) {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dsMaster);
}

@Bean(name = "dsMasterMysql")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mysqldatasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSourceMysql() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
@Bean(name = "jdbcMasterMysql")
public JdbcTemplate masterMysqlJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dsMasterMysql") DataSource dsMasterMysql) {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dsMasterMysql);
}
  }
```